# Укажите номера пропусков, на месте которых нужно поставить запятую в приведённом предложении:

Tags: пунктуация

От костра подымаются искорки огня (1)*и*(2) когда они чуть-чуть удаляются_(3)то мы начинаем фантазировать _(4) это вовсе не пылинки огня, а звёздочки _(5)плавно летящие в какие-то неведомые миры.

Comment: Не, Никита, так не пойдет: _укажите..._ Дайте свое решение — его проверят и объяснят ошибки.

Comment: Я ставил запятые в 1,2,3 и 5

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что д/з.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На месте цифр 1, 3 и 5 нужно поставить запятые. 
От костра подымаются искорки огня, и когда они чуть-чуть удаляются, то мы начинаем фантазировать: это вовсе не пылинки огня, а звёздочки, плавно летящие в какие-то неведомые миры.